# Calabash iOS and Android touches the wrong input element in a WebView

Tags: cordova, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

when trying to query and element with Calabash the query returns the element correctly but when trying to touch it it doesn't work! it touches the button under the element.

In our case we have a login screen, each element on the page has a unique ID, when we do `query "webView css:'input#USER_NAME'"` we get the element correctly but when we use `touch "webView css:'input#USER_NAME'"` it just don't work, it will try to touch the login in button for no reason !!

This issue happen on iOS and Android physical devices simulators, the version of calabash-android is 0.6.0 and calabash-ios is 0.16.4

by doing further investigation I found that the x and y attributes are not correct, calabash calculates the X and Y attributes wrong for our element and return wrong values

How to make calabash get the correct X and y?

Comment: I down voted because you did not provide enough information.  Does this problem happen on iOS _and_ Android?  What versions of Calabash iOS and Android are you using?  Is this on a physical device or emulator/simulator?

Comment: This issue happen on iOS and Android physical devices simulators, the version of calabash-android is 0.6.0 and calabash-ios is 0.16.4

Comment: Edit your _question_ with these details.

Comment: I added the info to the question

Comment: Try upgrading to Calabash-Android 0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

As Tobias suggests, you should update to the most recent iOS and Android versions:

- 0.7.0 Calabash Android
- 0.18.2 Calabash iOS

Comment: This issue happen on iOS and Android physical devices simulators, the version of calabash-android is 0.6.0 and calabash-ios is 0.16.4